# Android Studio Firebase Data Comparison with ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, match

There is an activity that I list the users who are registered with Firebase. Here all users are listed. There's also message activity. I want to list the people who just texted there. I have Chatlist in Firebase. The people who text here are id. The following code lists all users. Compare the user table with the Chatlist table if the ids match the message will be added to the activity. How can I make a change in this code for matching?

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, AllUserViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, AllUserViewHolder>
                    (
                            Users.class,
                            R.layout.user_item,
                            AllUserViewHolder.class,
                            usersRef

                    )
            {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final AllUserViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, final int position)
                {
                    final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();

                    usersRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                            {
                                final String userName =dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                                final String profileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                                final String biography = dataSnapshot.child("biography").getValue().toString();

                                viewHolder.setFullname(userName);
                                viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), profileImage);
                                viewHolder.setBiography(biography);

                                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                                {
                                                        userName + "profilini gör",
                                                        "Mesaj Gönder"
                                                };
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MessageActivity.this);
                                        builder.setTitle("Seç:");

                                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                            {
                                                if (i ==0)
                                                {
                                                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
                                                    profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                                                }
                                                if (i == 1)
                                                {
                                                    Intent chatIntent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                                                    chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                                    chatIntent.putExtra("userName", userName);
                                                    startActivity(chatIntent);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });
                                        builder.show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });




                }
            };
    usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than matching them one by one, you can just add all of them to an arraylist temporarily and then match contents of that arraylist to that of your `chatlist`.

```java
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This approach is not only better for you to consider, it will also be relatively easier to code.

If you are having some difficulties with the approach, please add your database structure and I can help you write a code for this.